# What are some different ways that you obtain metadata from SoundCloud after the API was inaccessible?

Tags: node.js, api, web-scraping, metadata, soundcloud

A while ago SoundCloud stopped people from registering client IDs to access their APIs. Ever since some people have tried the "get the client id from the browser" technique but sadly it has not worked for me. What happens is I always get a 403 forbidden error. This means I cannot obtain **public metadata** for tracks on SoundCloud using their API anymore.
What, you don't believe me? You try it!

Now, I'm considering two solutions (or more if anyone would be willing to suggest any):
1: Use youtube-dl to get the metadata only from a particular webpage on SoundCloud (Yes SoundCloud!)

Method 1 has worked for me on node.js (using no, no not the node-ytdl-core library BUT youtube-dl library [in the node package manager](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-dl&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiY2u-757roAhUI4HMBHeeFBukQFjAAegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw1vFvASEih0grYNJdeUe0Q5) which uses the binary). I have to say I'm impressed by the amount of metadata that is obtained, but sometimes it is RIDICULOUSLY slow, unusable when tracking 10+ tracks at a time.

2: Do some webscraping

I have not tried this method yet but I presume that it would take a while to load a webpage and that the scraping processing would be cumbersome, to say the least.

Has anyone got any ideas for other ways to approach this problem, or any ways I can directly access the SoundCloud API without any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this as a [reference](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/issues/2501).
Here is the response: 
[image]
Search for the **c=[{**, it'll always point to the track, otherwise it'll be empty.
But you can only retrieve public tracks.

It's a hassle way to retrieve the json, but it's better than nothing.